# PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY - the sence of this color transformation in Android

Tags: android, background-color, argb, colortransform, porter-duff

Under default Android theme I have three custom colored buttons by means of

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(customColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

[buttons http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1723/themew.jpg](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1723/themew.jpg)

When I switch to Theme.Holo by means of **/values-v11/styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

colors are changed to:

http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1659/themeholo.jpg

As I suspect, color of default button was changed in the new Holo Theme and being transformed with the same transformation parameter it gives unexpected colors. I would like to preserve initial colors. For this purpose I have to know transformation rules of **PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY**.  All that I have from Android docs is

```
[Sa * Da, Sc * Dc]
```

What does it means? Probably, **S** is a point of source bitmap (button drawable button.getBackground()) and **D** is a "point" of my customColor... How can I reproduce new transformed color from this formula? Does it means that new color **N** is:

```
[Na, Nr, Ng, Nb] = [Sa * Da, Sr * Dr, Sg * Dg, Sb * Db]
```

or what!?

**UPDATE:**
I suppose that:

1. **btn_default_normal.9.png** was used for above buttons in simple Android Theme
2. **btn_default_normal_holo_dark.9.png** is used for Android Holo Theme

To fix a problem with colors under Holo Theme, I want to make intermediate transformation from the second (Holo) color **#66999999** to the first color **#F2E1E1E1**:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(some_Intermediate_Color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

and then applay the same transformation as I have used before the new Holo theme was introduced. To calculate this intermediate color I have to solve two Diophantine equations in hexadecimal system where Na, Nc are in the interval [0, FF] and m, n - are integers:

```
66*Na = F2 + 100*m; => Na = 23
99*Nc = E1 + 100*n; =>  Nc = 89
```

Therefore, intermediate color is **#23898989**.

Unfortunately, implementing obtained intermediate color I still do not get desired colors as a result... Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the source is customColor and the destination is the button's background. Your formula is correct though.

Comment: what does PorterDuff.Mode.MULITPLY mean though?